# part outside textit also getting italicized

Tags: math-mode, italic

I am new to latex.
I am using Overleaf. When I type
Let \textbf{C_1, C_2} be two categories I get

[image]

I only want C_1 C_2 to be italicized. I don't understand why the rest is also getting italicized.
Please help me correct it

Comment: after an error fix the error, don't look at the PDF, which is not intended to be usable.

Comment: Why did you try to use `\textbf` to render something in (math-mode) italics?

Comment: @Mico, sorry I had tried both italics and bold and were giving the same error.

Comment: As you've discovered, neither `\textit` nor `\textbf` will switch from text to math mode, which is what's needed to process `C_1` and `C_2` properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using "_" outside of math mode, which is an error. Seeing the first "_" LaTeX is automatically put into math mode and keeps it to the very end.  Variables in math mode are set in italics, that's what you are seeing.

What you actually want is "Let $C_1$, $C_2$ be two categories".

Also see the error messages of your LaTeX compiler.

Comment: To be picky, you want `Let $C_1$, $C_2$ be...` : the comma is part of the phrase, not of the formula. You will get wrong spacing and line break behavior otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Rmano! I modified my answer accordingly.